# GNU parallel: why does diagnostic output look like sequential execution rather than parallel execution?

Tags: io, output, gnu-parallel

Scenario:

```
$ cat libs.txt
lib.a
lib1.a

$ cat t1a.sh
f1()
{
        local lib=$1
        stdbuf -o0 printf "job for $lib started\n"
        sleep 2
        stdbuf -o0 printf "job for $lib done\n"
}
export -f f1
cat libs.txt | SHELL=$(type -p bash) parallel --jobs 2 f1
```

Invocation and output:

```
$ time bash t1a.sh
job for lib.a started
job for lib.a done
job for lib1.a started
job for lib1.a done

real    0m2.129s
user    0m0.117s
sys     0m0.033s
```

Here we see that execution of `f1` was indeed in parallel (`real    0m2.129s`).

However, diagnostic output looks like execution was sequential.

I expected the following diagnostic output:

```
job for lib.a started
job for lib1.a started
job for lib.a done
job for lib1.a done
```

Why does diagnostic output look like sequential execution rather than parallel execution?

How to fix the diagnostic output so that it does look like parallel execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man pages of [GNU `parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html):

> ### `--group`
>
> Group output.
>
> **Output from each job is grouped together and is only printed when the
> command is finished.** Stdout (standard output) first followed by stderr
> (standard error).
>
> This takes in the order of 0.5ms CPU time per job and depends on the
> speed of your disk for larger output.
>
> **`--group` is the default.**
>
> See also: `--line-buffer` `--ungroup` `--tag`

[...]

> ### `--line-buffer`
>
> ### `--lb`
>
> Buffer output on line basis.
>
> `--group` will keep the output together for a whole job. `--ungroup` allows output to mixup with half a line coming from one job and half a
> line coming from another job. `--line-buffer` fits between these two:
> GNU parallel will print a full line, but will **allow for mixing lines
> of different jobs.**

So you should add either `--line-buffer` or `--ungroup` to your `parallel` command (according to your preferred behavior):

```
$ grep parallel t1a.sh 
cat libs.txt | SHELL=$(type -p bash) parallel --line-buffer --jobs 2 f1

$ bash t1a.sh 
job for lib.a started
job for lib1.a started
job for lib.a done
job for lib1.a done
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that `--group` is the default. Consider [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/768313/334715) question.