# Why does /usr/bin/time coupled with GNU parallel output results before command's output rather than after command's output?

Tags: cat, time, gnu-parallel

Scenario:

```
$ cat libs.txt
lib.a
lib1.a

$ cat t1a.sh
f1()
{
        local lib=$1
        stdbuf -o0 printf "job for $lib started\n"
        sleep 2
        stdbuf -o0 printf "job for $lib done\n"
}
export -f f1
/usr/bin/time -f "elapsed time %e" cat libs.txt | SHELL=$(type -p bash) parallel --line-buffer --jobs 2 f1

$ bash t1a.sh
elapsed time 0.00
job for lib.a started
job for lib1.a started
job for lib.a done
job for lib1.a done
```

Here we see that `elapsed time 0.00` appears *before* command's output. Why?

How to make `elapsed time 0.00` appear *after* command's output?

Comment: `/usr/bin/time` doesn't (and can't) time a pipeline like the bash shell keyword `time` can. You'll have to wrap the whole pipeline in `sh -c`.

Comment: Why? Because your `/usr/bin/time` measures `cat libs.txt` *only* and the `cat` is fast here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```shell
cat libs.txt | SHELL=$(type -p bash) /usr/bin/time -f "elapsed time %e" parallel --line-buffer --jobs 2 f1
```